# Ejaculation and the brain

Tags: sexuality, mind-and-matter, delusion

I’m just curious if anyone has noticed what I am noticing. When I ejaculate, in that exact moment, there is a weird sensation in my head. This sensation is about half the duration of the orgasm, so about one second long. it feels like something is literally being drained from my head in that moment.
Immediately, after this, I feel unclear and with slight brain fog - basically more delusion, I think. This brain fog takes about a day to get lifted.

So I’m wondering what this is and is it just me or is there’s any mention of any energy related stuff in Buddhism related to it? Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Their are chemical changes that happen in the brain with this. Nothing to do with Buddhism.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question doesn’t meet a Buddhism Stack Exchange guideline.

Comment: @YesheTenley Don't you think that is a rather simplistic approach. If it had nothing to do with buddhism, why did Buddha include in five precepts; why did the whole buddhism community split apart because of this (that arhats could experience orgasm) ? I think the moment is orgasm has high spiritual significance from experiential point of view (which is outside of materialistic metaphysical framework )

Comment: The question is the effect on the brain not the mind. Buddhism is interested in the latter.

Answer (score -1):

You are going through different feelings.
Before I begin to answer understand that mental fog is not a delusion.

First there was ignorance; with ignorance as a precondition came volitional formations; with volitional formations as a precondition came consciousness; with consciousness as a precondition came name and form ; with name and form as a precondition came six senses ; with six senses as a precondition came contact ; with contact as a precondition came feelings and these feelings will ultimately lead you to whole mass of suffering as with feelings as a precondition cravings will arise ; with cravings as precondition clinging will arise ; with clinging as a precondition attachments will arise ; with attachments as a precondition becoming has arisen ; with becoming as a precondition birth , rebirth , ageing , death and whole mass of suffering has arisen.

You better give up sex if you want Nibbana.